# Regarding the Struts-Default and json-default extensions

Tags: java, struts2

Hi i am new to struts2 in my project i am using json-default extension for the my registration page and validating it using validation.xml file and in the same project i am using the struts-default extensions for the login page. Is there any way to configure both the extension to work in my project?
this is my struts-register.xml

```
    <package name="default" extends="json-default">

    <action name="register" class="mypack.Register">

        <interceptor-ref name="jsonValidationWorkflowStack"></interceptor-ref>  


    <result name="input">/index.jsp</result>
    <result name="success">/welcome.jsp</result>

    </action>

</package>
```

struts-login.xml

```
<package name="login" namespace="/login" extends="struts-default">

    <action name="login" class="login.action.LoginAction">

    <result name="input">login/index.jsp</result>
    <result name="success">login/welcome.jsp</result>

    </action>

</package>
```

struts.xml file:

```
<struts>

<package name="default" extends="struts-default">

</package>
<include file="resources/login/struts-login.xml"></include>
<include file="resources/register/struts-register.xml"></include>
</struts>
```

here action is not getting performed in when i click on the registration button i need to integrate both the files and run them?
This is my project structure

[image]

Comment: Where are those config files located and deployed to?

Comment: my project structure as follows

Comment: No no, add information to the question, not in comments.

Answer (score 2):

your question is not clear to me. If you want to extends both 'struts-default` and 'json-default' in same package use

```
 <package name="example1" extends="struts-default, json-default">
    <action name="fetchComments" class="example.ListJson">
        <result  type="json"></result>
    </action>
</package>
```